# NumberFormatException when passing variable through Android Intent

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass 2 variables through a couple of Android Activities. One of them keeps turning up as null on the last page:

The first Activity:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(RoundOptionActivity.this, MoveOptionActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("numRounds", "5");
startActivity(intent);
```

The second Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
    numRounds = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("numRounds"));
}

.........

Intent intent = new Intent(MoveOptionActivity.this, MoveActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("numRounds", numRounds);
intent.putExtra("playerChoice", playerChoice);
startActivity(intent);
```

(Note that at this point I printed numRounds in LogCat and it was set to the right number, and not null)

The Third Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
    playerChoice = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("playerChoice"));
    numRounds = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("numRounds"));
}
```

At this point, the application crashes at the line where I try to parse numRounds to an integer, with a NumberFormatException complaining that it can't parse a null value. There's never a problem with playerChoice, only numRounds. I've tried handling numRounds the exact same way as playerChoice, but nothing seems to work. What's going on? D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `extras.getInt("numRounds");`

because in second `Activity` you added to `putExtra` **int** value:

```
numRounds = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("numRounds"));
```

Comment: Ah! I actually tried that before and it said there wasn't any such method. Also I don't know why it worked parsing it as an int in the 2nd Activity but not the 3rd, very odd. Anyway, that worked, thanks! =)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
numRounds = extras.getInt("numRounds");
```

intead of

```
numRounds = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("numRounds"));
```

because you are passing **numRounds** as Integer in `intent.putExtra("numRounds", numRounds);` from second Activity

or pass as if you want to receive as String:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MoveOptionActivity.this, MoveActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("numRounds", numRounds+"");
intent.putExtra("playerChoice", playerChoice);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @AlexLockwood : see this numRounds = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("numRounds"));

Comment: Yeah, but he used `intent.putExtra("numRounds", "5");` to store the `String` in the first place.

Comment: ohhhh, it was in the 2nd activity that he inserted the `int`. K, makes sense then :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood : see The second Activity:

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
    numRounds = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("numRounds"));
} he is parsing String to int here and then passing int

Answer (score 1):

As far as i think in your second activity you are setting numRounds a integer value in putExtra() i.e the integer variable numRounds thats why it causing problem. either get the numRounds in third activity as directly like `extras.getInt("numRounds")` or send value as String in second activity i.e`intent.putExtra("numRounds", numRounds+"");`